# AppStore require apps for iPhone and iPad to be build with iOS 13 SDK after June 30, 2020

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore

Is possible to build and deploy the first versions of the app with iOS 12 SDK, before the deadline(June 30, 2020) and after that to upgrade to iOS 13 SDK the app and the new updates so all the users will have the minimum first versions of the app, but the new updates after June 30, 2020, to be for users that can and have iOS 13?

Can someone guide me towards a tutorial or something to clarify if it is possible and how should I approach this?

Comment: I have a question to this requirement from Apple. Do they men that any new or updates to an existing app requires to be build with the 13 SDK? Or do they mean that all existing apps in the store must be rebuild? And if that is the case, will they then remove apps that does not fulfill the requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is entirely possible. It is just setting the target version to iOS 12 in the first version, and iOS 13 in the second version. You will have to set the iOS 13 release to be timed for release on 30th of June, but apart from that there's nothing "special" in this.

Note: It seems you might have mixed some things up. The deadline requirement for June 30th 2020 is just that the app is to be built with the iOS 13 SDK - it doesn't mean that you have to set your target deployment version to iOS 13. So you can definitely build with iOS 13 SDK to fulfill the deadline requirement, and still only require iOS 11 or iOS 12 or whatever you need.

Users on iOS 12 (or even earlier) should have no problems running apps built with the iOS 13 SDK as long as the target deployment version is set accordingly.

Comment: After the 30th of June when I will push the new version to AppStore, with the build target iOS 13, will the previous version of the app (iOS 12 build target) be available for the iOS 12 users?

Comment: Yes, by default. You can manage iCloud download settings from the Pricing tab in the developer account.

Comment: so even after the deadline a user that has an iPhone 6 running iOS 12 can download the app from App Store?

Comment: I have just edited my answer - I think you're confusing the build requirement with a target version requirement. The deadline just says that you have to build your app with the iOS 13 SDK (i.e. install the latest Xcode and build, and you're good to go). It doesn't mean that you have to require iOS 13 for your users - not at all. You can still build apps that are meant for iOS 10, iOS 11, etc. etc. without any problems. It doesn't have any impact on your users.